# Ubuntu 16.04.1 don't work vith mobile broadband

Tags: networking, mobile-broadband

I have tried everything but without results.
The closest I've come to is that the signal has shown "cable connection established" and I have printed an ethernet connection. But nevertheless there was no connection!
So I'm still referring to using Windows, which I hate.
However, I must admit that as far as internet connection is concerned, Windows is light years ahead of Ubuntu.
Anyone who has a qualified answer?

Comment: How do you know there is "no connection"? What error messages do you get and from what?